# sudo as another user with their environment

Tags: bash, sudo, environment-variables

```
$ whoami
admin
$ sudo -S -u otheruser whoami
otheruser
$ sudo -S -u otheruser /bin/bash -l -c 'echo $HOME'
/home/admin
```

**Why isn't `$HOME` being set to `/home/otheruser` even though bash  is invoked as a login shell?**

Specifically, `/home/otheruser/.bashrc` isn't being sourced.
Also, `/home/otheruser/.profile` isn't being sourced. - (`/home/otheruser/.bash_profile` doesn't exist)

Comment: You might want to try `sudo machinectl shell --uid username` as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/754723/22222).

Answer (score 147, accepted):

To invoke a login shell using `sudo` just use `-i`. When command is not specified you'll get a login shell prompt, otherwise you'll get the output of your command.

Example (login shell):

```
sudo -i
```

Example (with a specified user):

```
sudo -i -u user
```

Example (with a command):

```
sudo -i -u user whoami
```

Example (print user's `$HOME`):

```
sudo -i -u user echo \$HOME
```

Note: The backslash character ensures that the dollar sign reaches the target user's shell and is not interpreted in the calling user's shell.

I have just checked the last example with *strace* which tells you exactly what's happening. The output bellow shows that the shell is being called with `--login` and with the specified command, just as in your explicit call to bash, but in addition *sudo* can do its own work like setting the `$HOME`.

```
# strace -f -e process sudo -S -i -u user echo \$HOME
execve("/usr/bin/sudo", ["sudo", "-S", "-i", "-u", "user", "echo", "$HOME"], [/* 42 vars */]) = 0
...
[pid 12270] execve("/bin/bash", ["-bash", "--login", "-c", "echo \\$HOME"], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0
...
```

I noticed that you are using `-S` and I don't think it is generally a good technique. If you want to run commands as a different user without performing authentication from the keyboard, you might want to use SSH instead. It works for `localhost` as well as for other hosts and provides public key authentication that works without any interactive input.

```
ssh user@localhost echo \$HOME
```

Note: You don't need any special options with SSH as the SSH server always creates a login shell to be accessed by the SSH client.

Comment: `sudo -i -u user echo \$HOME` doesn't work for me. Output: `$HOME`. strace gives the same output as yours. What's the issue?

Comment: No idea, it still works for me, I'd need to see it or maybe even touch the system.

Comment: While `sudo -i` should be a login shell it is different from what `sudo su -` does on Arch linux. A clear sign the former does not do a login is that it does not display the last login time but that the latter does (and it does a lot more, like have a lot of envvars ready).

Comment: @John_West Because `$HOME` is expanded before it's sent to `sudo`. `echo '$HOME'` works, though.

Answer (score 14):

You're giving Bash too much credit. All "login shell" means to Bash is what files are sourced at startup and shutdown. The `$HOME` variable doesn't figure into it.

The Bash docs explain some more what login shell means: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files

In fact, Bash doesn't do anything to set `$HOME` at all. `$HOME` is set by whatever invokes the shell (login, ssh, etc.), and the shell inherits it. Whatever started your shell as admin set `$HOME` and then exec-ed `bash`, `sudo` by design doesn't alter the environment unless asked or configured to do so, so `bash` as otheruser inherited it from your shell.

If you want `sudo` to handle more of the environment in the way you're expecting, look at the `-i` switch for sudo. Try:

```
sudo -S -u otheruser -i /bin/bash -l -c 'echo $HOME'
```

The man page for sudo describes it in more detail, though not really well, I think: http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo

Comment: $HOME isn't set by bash - Thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: Look for *strace* in my answer. It shows that you don't need to build `/bin/bash -l -c 'echo $HOME'` command line yourself when using `-i`.

Comment: That `sudo` syntax threw an error on my machine. (`su` uses the `-c` option, but I don't think `sudo` does.) I had better luck with: `HomeDir=$( sudo -u "$1" -H -s echo "\$HOME" )`

Comment: yeah, @palswim is right. Not sure about `-S` (I didn't need it, so I left it out), but `-c` doesn't work here, you need `-s` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -u www-data bash -i -c "env"
```

Notice the `-i` flag, telling bash to run interactively.

This command will execute an interactive bash shell for user `www-data`, within which shell (as an example) the `env` command is executed.

This works even if user `www-data` has a *nologin* shell as their default shell.